# use as3 NativeProcess to run windows cmd

Tags: actionscript-3, cmd

I used the NativeProcess to run my .cmd file to use the convert of Imagemagick on Windows.

the cmd is

```
convert -resize 1%x2% 3% 4%
```

On my computer,it looked normal.
But on some other computer,the bug looked like the “-resize” was be garbled.

then I changed the cmd

```
convert 1% 2%x3% 4% 5%
```

but on some computer，it still have the bug.

Is that the air output UTF-8,and the windows CMD use Unicode?

How to use it will not produce this error?

my code is

```
private var mProcess:NativeProcess;
private function convertImgToTargetPng(filePath:String,resultFilePath:String,width:Number,height:Number,scale:Number=1):void
{
    var convertFile:File =  File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("script").resolvePath("convert.cmd");
    var nativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = convertFile;
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.userDirectory;

    var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    processArgs.push("-resize");
    processArgs.push(width*scale);
    processArgs.push(height*scale);
    processArgs.push(filePath);
    processArgs.push(resultFilePath);
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
    mProcess = new NativeProcess();
    mProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onConvertErrorHandler);
    mProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onConvertExitHandler);
    try
    {
        mProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    }
    catch (e : Error)
    {
        Alert.show("convert failed: " + e.message);
    }

}

private function onConvertErrorHandler(event : ProgressEvent):void
{
    var data:String = mProcess.standardError.readUTFBytes(mProcess.standardError.bytesAvailable);
    Alert.show("convert error :" + data);
}

private function onConvertExitHandler(event : NativeProcessExitEvent):void
{
    mProcess.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onConvertErrorHandler);
    mProcess.removeEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onConvertExitHandler);

    Alert.show("convert success");
}
```

Comment: Show AS3 code of how you setup the arguments for your **NativeProcess**. Usually do something like :  `args.push('-resize', '640x480', 'myOption3', 'myOption4' )` replace 640x480 with your own numbers. Why do you have `1%x2%`? Are those references to some other variables? Show things we need know, to answer you correctly

Comment: check my answer. I dont have imagemagick for testing, but it should be useful for a result.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you can try...

Make a changed CMD file that looks like: `convert 1% 2% 3% 4%`

and update your AS3 code section to look like this...

```
var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    processArgs.push("-resize");

    processArgs.push(String ( String(width*scale) + "x" + String(height*scale) ) );

    processArgs.push(filePath);

    processArgs.push(resultFilePath);
```

Let me now how it goes.

Also instead of a **.cmd** file, why not just run the process with **convert.exe** file itself? : 
If that **convert.exe** is located here : *c:\program files\imagemagick\convert.exe* 
 Then use path location in AS3 code as `c:\\program files\\imagemagick\\convert.exe`

```
private function convertImgToTargetPng(filePath:String,resultFilePath:String,width:Number,height:Number,scale:Number=1):void
{
    //# Use your location of convert.exe
    var convertFile : File = new File("C:\\imageMagick\\converter.exe"); 

    if ( convertFile.exists ) //# If found in your location  
    {  
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); //vc
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = convertFile;  
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.userDirectory;

        var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        processArgs.push("-resize");
        processArgs.push(String ( String(width*scale) + "x" + String(height*scale) ) );
        processArgs.push(filePath);
        processArgs.push(resultFilePath);

        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
        mProcess = new NativeProcess();
        mProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onConvertErrorHandler);
        mProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onConvertExitHandler);

        try { mProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo); }
        catch (e : Error)
        { Alert.show("convert failed: " + e.message); }
    }

}
```